# Hibernate merge does not delete OneToMany old entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities:

`Seminar` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "seminars")
public class Seminar {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "seminar")
    private List<SeminarParticipation> participations;
...
}
```

`SeminarParticipation` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "seminar_participations")
public class SeminarParticipation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="seminar_id", nullable=false)
    private Seminar seminar;
...
}
```

In DAO, I use EntityManager to work with seminars like this:

```
em.persist(seminar)
em.merge(seminar)
em.remove(seminar)
```

When saving or deleting `Seminar` entities, records in `seminar_participations` are created/deleted as well.

But when I try to update a seminar (after setting new `List<SeminarParticipation>` of participations) using `merge` method, new records there are created in according to the list, but old ones are not deleted.

Persisting code:

1) Controller code (I've also tried to update the existing list, it does not work as well):

```
seminar.setParticipations(newParticipations);
seminarService.updateSeminar(seminar);
```

2) Service class

```
@Service
public class SeminarServiceImpl implements SeminarService {

@Autowired
private SeminarDAO seminarDAO;

@Override
    public void updateSeminar(Seminar seminar) {
        seminarDAO.update(seminar);
    }
...
}
```

3) DAO class

```
@Repository
public class SeminarDAOImpl implements SeminarDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(Seminar seminar) {
        em.merge(seminar);
    }
...
}
```

How I can solve this problem? Is there a way without deleting them manually in DAO?

Comment: Are you specifying what you want to delete?

Comment: Ah wait, I see what you mean. You just want to use merge then if you want to update. `persist` and and `remove` are not needed. At least I think I know what you want. Because having `persist` `merge` and `remove` all in one for one object is... well I've never seen that

Comment: Sorry, I mean only that I use that methods, not that I invoke them in this order in one time :)

Comment: Do not replace the list. Clear the existing list and then add the new records to the existing list. seminar.getParticipations().clear(); seminar.getParticipations().addAll(...);

Comment: where is the actual persistence code used to delete and merge?

Comment: @AlanHay, I've tried thos approach. Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: @NeilStockton, added

Answer (score 4):

You should try using [orphanRemoval = true](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/OneToMany/orphanRemoval) parameter for @OneToMany.

Answer (score 0):

use `em.flush()` before removing the elements.